# how to make CodeIgniter 4 sessions available in other methods of the same controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-4

So I'm having a problem with CodeIgniter session class. When I declare a session variable in the constructor function, it is available to every method of my controller. When I only initialise in the constructor and try setting sessions in other methods however, it is not working. When I try to var_dump the variable, it returns null. I even tried changing session path to \writable\sessions in .env to no luck Here is the code I'm working with.

```
    class Home extends BaseController

{

public function __construct() {

$this->session = session();

$this->session->set('age', ''); //allows me to retrieve age in any method in this controller



}



        public function sm() {


$this->session->set('email', 'something@gmail.com'); //I am not able to access in other methods

}



    public function index()

{



$email = $this->session->email;

echo var_dump($email); //returns null

$age = $this->session->age;

echo var_dump($age); //returns data type etc. IE this session set in the constructor is working.

    }

}
```

I apologise in advance for the bad formatting.
Thank you.

Comment: I copy your code to my Home controller (and import session class `use CodeIgniter\Session\Session;`, add a route to **sm** method, 1st call **sm** method, and call the **index** method then the email is set in session

Comment: That actually works. After commenting to narrow down the issue, it looks like the import / use CodeIgniter\Session\Session; is what did the trick. I actually never thought of this, because I asumed everything was fine since I am extending BaseController. Thanks big time.